# Material MatInputModule not working angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I am using Angular Material component https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview 
but Material animation is not working

package dependency

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.2.1",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/forms": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/material": "^9.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/router": "~9.1.1",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

},

App.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {PostCreateComponent} from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { PostListComponent } from './posts/post-list/post-list.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostCreateComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    PostListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule, MatCardModule,MatButtonModule,MatToolbarModule,MatExpansionModule,MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

HTML:

```
  <form >

...
...
    <mat-form-field>

      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Title">

    </mat-form-field>
 .....
....
  </form>
```

CSS-

```
mat-card{

  background-color: lavender;
  box-shadow: currentColor;

}
mat-form-field,
textarea{
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

button{
  background-color: indigo;
  color: ivory;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Did you add the Css?

Answer (score 0):

What the version of **Angular material** you are using?

to know version open your `package.json` file and search for **@angular/material**

If you version is less than or equal **8.0.0** the import module in `app.module.ts` will be this format:

> `import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material`

And don't forget to import it in imports array

> imports: [
> MatInputModule
> }

If you version is higher than **8.0.0** the import module in `app.module.ts` will be this format:

> `import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';`

And don't forget to import it in imports array

> imports: [
> MatInputModule
> }

Answer (score -2):

Please import `MatInputModule` in `@NgModule` decorator of corresponding module like this;

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: It is already imported in the imports in the original question though?